# Не расспознается @ при использовании react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, mobx

Подключил npm-пакет mobx-react и при запуске выкидывает такую ошибку

> Syntax error: C:/..../index.jsx: Unexpected token (4:0)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> . !!! автор вопроса не использует TS (`.jsx`)
>   -> предполагается использование `Babel`
>   -> о нём и речь в тексте ниже

судя по тому, что декараторы вы называете собачкой - я настоятельно рекомендую:

1. для начала ознакомьтесь вот с этой статьёй на хабре https://habr.com/post/277021/, ещё можно заглянуть сюда https://learn.javascript.ru/decorators и сюда https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators#decorators.
2. затем - затем, по хорошему, необходимо пощупать, поиграться с декораторами, но тут встаёт вопрос, какой плагин использовать https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-decorators

   - babel-plugin-transform-decorators
   - babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy
   - **UPD:**
     а вот, на [сайте npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy) вообще рекомендуют для `Babel >= 7.x`
     `@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators`

---

**что говорит документация `mobx`**

вкратце:

1. установи `babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy`
2. включи его в `.babelrc` вот так

   ```
   {
       "presets": ["es2015", "stage-1"],
       "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy"]
   }
   ```

> https://mobx.js.org/best/decorators.html#enabling-decorator-syntax
>
> Babel: manually enabling decorators
>
> To enable support for decorators without using the mobx preset, follow the following steps. Install support for decorators: `npm i --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy`. And enable it in your `.babelrc` file:
>
> ```
> {
>   "presets": ["es2015", "stage-1"],
>   "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy"]
> }
> ```
>
> Note that the order of plugins is important: `transform-decorators-legacy` should be listed *first*. Having issues with the babel setup? Check this [issue](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/105) first.
>
> For babel 7, see [issue 1352](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/1352) for an example setup.

---

я попробовал собрать проект вот с такими конфигами

**package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.1.0",
  "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "1.3.5",
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["transform-decorators-legacy"]
    // или так
    //["transform-decorators-legacy", {"decoratorsBeforeExport": true}]
  ]
}
```

но получил ошибку

> Error: The 'decorators' plugin requires a 'decoratorsBeforeExport' option, whose value must be a boolean. If you are migrating from Babylon/Babel 6 or want to use the old decorators proposal, you should use the 'decorators-legacy' plugin instead of 'decorators'.

и на этом мой интерес к вопросу угас.

---

если мой ответ вас не устраивает - рекомендую:

1. найти статью с подробным описанием установки и настройки проекта, попробовать, если не получится указать её в вопросе.
2. приложить к вопросу содержимое файлов `package.json` и `.babelrc`, а лучше ссылку на минимальный проект на `github`.
3. ну и наконец - запастись чаем, пряниками и терпением : ) в ожидании адептов бабел/реакт/флов

Comment: А вот мешать шестой и седьмой бабель не стоит, право же... Тебе и самому не мешает ознакомиться с руководством по миграции на 7 бабель!

Comment: @Piterden, я так понял, что тут дело не только в бабеле, но и в том, какую спеку(стадию спеки) реализует плагин и соответственно либа на основе этого плагина ? P.S.: вон, на сайте npm вообще рекомендуют для `Babel >= 7.x` `@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators` P.P.S.:  я из адептов TS :D заглянул ради https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pipeline-operator

Comment: Тоже бы использовал TS, если бы не MS )) Кстати с 7 бабелем я намучился тут недавно. Однако завёл)